# How to find "0" values rather than empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet containing 8 columns of data, A-H, each of which is a different length and may contain values of "0" which I need deleting. Rather than do this with a loop, I'm trying to do this using the .Find method but I'm becoming unstuck as the find method keeps classifying empty cells (where a column is shorter than the max length column) as zeros. When the function finds one of these cells it selects and deletes a cell at the top of that column rather than selecting the specific cell. I've tried using my code using values other than 0 and it works fine so it's a problem with excel classifying empty cells as "0".

Is there a way to search specifically for the value "0"? I've tried using str(0) to specify a string value of "0" but get the same result. A subset of my code as it stands is:

```
Row = wf.Max(Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row, Cells(Rows.Count,8).End(xlUp_.Row

'Originally I had zero = 0 or "0" but I tried the following to get a string version
zero = Str(0)
zerofix = Right(zero,1)

Do While Check_Val_Existence(zerofix,Row) = True
   Set aCell = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(Row,8)).Find(What:=zerofix,LookIn:=xlValues)
   If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
      aCell.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
Loop
```

where

```
Function Check_Val_Existence(ByVal Srch, ByVal Row) As Boolean

Dim rFnd As Range

Set rFnd = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(Row,8)).Find(What:=Srch)
If Not rFnd Is Nothing Then
   Check_Val_Existence = True
Else
   Check_Val_Existence = False
End If

End Function
```

I'd rather not have to loop through the code and search each column in turn but it's beginning to look like I might have to do just that.

Comment: Could you post a little bit of sample data as well please?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting SO to format the data correctly, but basically I have 8 columns of data, each of which can contain any number of rows (at the moment this is between 234 and 269 rows) which are filled with numbers. You could create dummy data just by putting random numbers in cells, just make sure that the columns are of differing length and there are some 0 values scattered about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Sheet1.Cells.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlwhole, SearchOrder:= _
xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

This will clear all cells which have "0"

If you want to delete the cells which have "0" then you can also use `.Find` and `.FindNext`. See this link

**Topic**: .Find and .FindNext In Excel VBA

**Link**: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

**Quote from that link**

> In this tutorial, I will stress on how to use .Find to make your search faster.
>
> The syntax of .Find is
>
> expression.Find(What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat)
>
> Where
>
> Expression (Required): is any valid range Object. So if we take the above example then the range would be Range(“A1:A” & lastRow)
>
> What (Optional Variant): is the “Search value”
>
> After (Optional Variant): The cell after which you want the search to begin.
>
> LookIn (Optional Variant): The type of information. (xlValues or xlFormulas)
>
> LookAt (Optional Variant): Can be one of the following XlLookAt (constants): xlWhole or xlPart.
>
> SearchOrder (Optional Variant): Can be one of the following XlSearchOrder constants: xlByRows or xlByColumns.
>
> SearchDirection: Can be one of these XlSearchDirection constants. xlNext default xlPrevious
>
> MatchCase (Optional Variant): True to make the search case sensitive. The default value is False.
>
> MatchByte (Optional Variant): Used only if you’ve selected or installed double-byte language support. True to have double-byte characters match only double-byte characters. False to have double-byte characters match their single-byte equivalents.
>
> SearchFormat (Optional Variant): The search format.

Comment: That works great, but is there a way to Delete the cells rather than clear them?

Comment: Sid, I think the issue is the false matches on the Find routine

Comment: The important part is how one uses `.Find`... With `LookAt:=xlwhole` or `LookAt:=xlpart`. `LookAt:=xlpart` will give you false matches. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I was referring to `find method keeps classifying empty cells (where a column is shorter than the max length column) as zeros` - which i don't think is a partial v whole match issue. But I can't duplicate the false flagging issue so I need some further clarity ....

Comment: @ brettdj My problem was coming from the fact that I have columns of different lengths, so Column A contains 239 rows of data say and Column B contains 260 rows of data, but they both contain some "0" values. When I ran my code it would identify the blank cells at the bottom of Column A as zeros and then select the cell at the top of Column A for deletion. That said using 'LookAt:=xlWhole' is working perfectly, Thanks @Siddharth Rout!

Answer (score 0):

Rather then work with *all cells*, do the prelim work to define the range of interest - i.e. cells that have numbers in them either entered as constants or as formulae. This excludes your blank cels from the search which will both speed up your code, and eliminate the false flags.

In this example `rng3` returns the cells of interest on the `ActiveSheet`. You would then run your `Find` routine on this range

```
Sub LookAtZeros()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
Set rng2 = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
Set rng3 = Union(rng1, rng2)
Else
Set rng3 = rng1
End If
Else
If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then Set rng3 = rng2
End If
If Not rng3 Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Range with numeric constants and/or numeric formulae is " & rng3.Address(0, 0)
Else
MsgBox "no numbers", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd not actually considered doing it this way, a very nice work-around to the problem. That said rather than add another Sub to what is a rapidly growing spreadsheet I think I'll go for the other answer as it solves the problem in a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to do a general replace of 0 to =0/0, which should give an error (and still gives you a way to restore the values back to 0 if needed, due to the unique calculation), then do a find/select special errors.